# Some specific sort of tail-recursion in scala

Tags: scala, tail-recursion

I would like to understand, how those sort of tail-recursion will be executed under the hood, I saw recently in one of the big-data assignment written in scala. I provide also two additional versions of the implementation, how I would rather write this code - one of them is also tail-recursive, and the other one - not; However, I would like to understand, how the first implementation, provides the same result.

So, here it is (aim is to find an index of the specific name (tag) in the list (ls)):

```
def firstLangInTag(tag: Option[String], ls: List[String]): Option[Int] = {
if (tag.isEmpty) None
else if (ls.isEmpty) None
else if (tag.get == ls.head) Some(0)
else {
  val tmp = firstLangInTag(tag, ls.tail)
  tmp match {
     case None => None
     case Some(i) => Some(i + 1)
     }
  }
}
```

When we think about execution, it will be seen as follows for parameters 'tag' defined as Option("Scala"), and 'ls' as List("Java", "PHP", "Scala"):

- val tmp = firstLangInTag(Scala, (PHP, Scala)) => returns Some(2)
- val tmp = firstLangInTag(Scala, (Scala)) => returns Some(1)

So we have an answer Some(2) and it is correct, but could someone please explain, where is var 'i' (implicated var 'tmp') saved during execution. Is it because, tail-recursion provides one stack for each recursive execution and 'i' just saved in memory and will be updated every time during iteration? Why var 'tmp' will not just overwritten by each iteration, but rather the result will accumulated (+ 1). If you look at following implementations with 'accumulator', but recursive again, then it is pretty clear, that result have been stored in variable called 'acc', thus 'acc' returns the result of this function:

```
def firstLangInTag(tag: Option[String], ls: List[String]): Option[Int] = {
   def counter(acc: Int, tag: Option[String], ls: List[String]): Int = {
     if (tag.isEmpty) acc
     else if (ls.isEmpty) acc
     else if (tag.get == ls.head) acc
     else counter(acc + 1, tag, ls.tail) 
   }
   Option(counter(0, tag, ls))
```

Similarly, we can also achieve the same result as not tail-recursive function (providing that, it will be returned Int instead of Option):

```
...
else 1 + firstLangInTag(tag, ls.tail);
```

But, please, could someone explain me the first function and how scala makes it possible to store the result in the VAL and in addition update it by each next iteration;

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'll let someone who is more versed in Scala give a more detailed answer about the contents of the stack at each phase of execution, but I do notice that `tmp` is set to the return value of a function.  No intermediate values are being stored while the list is being traversed in the forward direction, but each call to firstLangIntTag applies a function to the result of the call returning to it.  This is possible because functions are objects in Scala.

Answer (score 0):

E.g `val tmp = firstLangInTag(Some("Scala"), List("PHP", "C#", "Scala")) => returns Some(2)`

In above example you will have three calls of your function. Every earlier to return the result has to wait for execution following him:

- 1st `firstLangInTag(Some("Scala"), List("PHP", "C#", "Scala"))`
- 2nd `firstLangInTag(Some("Scala"), List("C#", "Scala"))`
- 3rd `firstLangInTag(Some("Scala"), List("Scala"))`

Last call will return `Some(0)` which will be propagated to the second call where `tmp` will be resolved as `Some(0)` and returned to the first call `Some(1)`.

Finally, the first call `tmp` will be resolved as `Some(1)` then matched and function will return `Some(2)`.

The first solution in not tail-recursive because first call of the function need wait to the function call (with the tail of the list) that find tag or return None in case of lack of tag in initial list.

To resolve this without unnecessary overhead on the stack using the version with accumulator and add `@tailrec` annotation

When you try to write tail-recursive function you always could add a `@tailrec` annotation so that you can be sure if function is not implemented properly you will receive an error message.

Comment: thank you, but could you please explain, how VAL tmp can be updated? Is it smth. to do with match - method in scala, where some temporary variable (such as 'i' in the example) will be updated and then evaluated by VAL? Cause as the function will be propagated, I do understand, how it will be updated - unfortunately, I do not! That't why I provided example with accumulator (purely tail-recursive function), where it is very clear, what will be returned and how.

Comment: The val is not updated. It's a completely new one on each instance of the method call.

Comment: Each method call have its own space on stack, so each function call have its own instance of every variables.

Answer (score 0):

The first given function is not tail-recursive. Add the `@scala.annotation.tailrec` annotation to it, and compilation fails. You are right to be skeptical of how the part dealing with `tmp` and `i` works since that's precisely the part that prevents it from being tail-recursive.

Comment: Not completely accurate. It's still not tail recursive because the return value is further processed (matched against) and not immediately returned.

Comment: I was also a little bit sceptical about, whether the first example is tail-recursive or not...